# What's the difference between Foo().Result and Task.Run(() => Foo()).Result in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, deadlock

In C# what is the difference between these two statements? If I use the first one in my constructor in my test classes I get a deadlock, or something similar, and the tests never finish. With the second one the code works.

```
// Deadlock.
var r = MyMethod().Result;

// Works.
var r = Task.Run(() => MyMethod()).Result;
```

Update: There is a bit more context in this commit: https://github.com/webCRMdotcom/erp-integrations/pull/92/commits/dd8af89899ce1de837ef6e34f0688a685a5cea3b.

Comment: Both are probably wrong, overall. If `MyMethod` is returning a `Task<T>` then the first leads to deadlock and the second ends up just assigning the `Task<T>` to `r` without obtaining the *result* from that `Task` (`Task.Run` ended up creating a `Task<Task<T>>` in this case).

Comment: I have more context here: https://github.com/webCRMdotcom/erp-integrations/pull/92/commits/dd8af89899ce1de837ef6e34f0688a685a5cea3b. I don't need to write `.Result` twice, as @Chrᴉz mentions.

Comment: @JanAagaard You're right. My fault.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: `r` is assigned to type `T` and nok `Task<T>`. Maybe this was changed at some point, because @Chrᴉz also pointed this out, but I cannot confirm this. I've added a link to the commit, so that there is a bit more context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is the starting thread context.

Here a simple sample

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string r;
        OutputThreadInfo("Main");
        r = MyMethod().Result;
        r = Task.Run( () => MyMethod() ).Result;
    }

    public static async Task<string> MyMethod()
    {
        OutputThreadInfo("MyMethod");
        await Task.Delay(50);
        return "finished";
    }

    private static void OutputThreadInfo(string context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",context,System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L26UvF)

which will output

```
Main 32
MyMethod 32
MyMethod 63
```

The first call of MyMethod will start at the same thread as Main and if started from a thread with a synchronization context it will block.

The second call of MyMethod will start from a different thread (worker thread from thread pool) as Main which does not have a synchronization context and therefor will not block.

PS You should keep in mind that Console applications do not have a synchronization context as default but WinForms, WPF, UWP application do have and so will behave somehow different on async/await

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Result` and `Task.Wait` block the current thread you should use `await` for this to work without any problems. (Though they only block if not already completed).

The second line will create a task and will start it's execution on a available thread in the Thread Pool and that's why it doesn't block.
This is because the `Task` construct when used with `async-await` will generate a State Machine that keeps track of all the awaits used in the code block and when all finishes then it can return the result. Keep in mind thought that depending on the Synchronization Context you are in, the code after `await` may run on a different thread then the one the task started.

So what I do when I have to execute synchronous an async method I use a small piece of code like this:

```
private static readonly TaskFactory _tf = new TaskFactory(
        CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
{      
  return _tf.StartNew<Task<TResult>>((Func<Task<TResult>>) (() =>
  {
    return func();
  })).Unwrap<TResult>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Keep in mind that, if needed, you have to use the same `CultureInfo` inside the `RunSync` `StarNew` task factory call so you won't have this kind of problems.

Comment: (The reason that I am not using `await` is that I am calling the code inside a constructor.)

Comment: @JanAagaard You should avoid this if you can. Constructors should be lightweight. If you need to do heavy work to setup an instance (which the usage of tasks/async implies) you should use a static async Create method and make the constructor private, or if that is not possible (because you use dependency injection) use an async Initialize method to do the work.

Comment: @ckuri. Thanks. I actually have static Create methods pretty much throughout the code base. It works out nicely, except for the tests, where I currently have this `Task.Run()` syntax. Might migrate to lightweight constructors and private Initialize methods, combined with a bit of boilerplate, so that the classes themselves make sure to initialize when needed.